# How to sendkeys element using R programming?

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have tried to sendkeysElement using R programming. Here is my code

```
require(RSelenium)
remdir<-remoteDriver()
remdir$open()

remdir$navigate("http://www.flipkart.com")
sbox<-remdr$findElement(using = 'name',"q")

sbox$sendkeysToElement(list("laptops",key="enter"))
```

But I got the error like this

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of typo's which maybe an issue. The code works with chrome:

```
require(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
remdir<- rD$client
remdir$open()

remdir$navigate("http://www.flipkart.com")
sbox <- remdir$findElement(using = 'name',"q")

sbox$sendKeysToElement(list("laptops",key="enter"))
rm(rD)
gc()
```